# Continue the main loop

Tags: unity-game-engine, continue

Okay, so I have a loop inside a loop and I want to tell the first loop to continue when an if statement inside the second loop is true. The following code does not work, but how can I make it work with adding minimal code. Thanks in advance! I am working in Unity3D btw.

```
public void AssignNearby(List<GameObject> _nodeList, GameObject _current)
{
    nearby.Clear();
    foreach(GameObject node in _nodeList)
    {
    int nodeId = node.GetComponent<NodeScript>()._ID;
        foreach(int allergie in allergies)
        {
            if(nodeId == allergie || nodeId == identity)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

Vector3 curPos = _current.transform.position;
Vector3 nearPos = node.transform.position;

    switch(identity)
    {
        case 1:
            if(nodeId == 5)
            {
                node.renderer.material.color = Color.black;
                nearby.Add(node);
                goto case 2;
            }
        break;
        case 2: case 3: case 4: case 6:
            if(Mathf.Abs(curPos.x - nearPos.x) + Mathf.Abs(curPos.y - nearPos.y) + Mathf.Abs(curPos.z - nearPos.z) < 2)
            {
                node.renderer.material.color = Color.black;
                nearby.Add(node);
            }
        break;
        case 5:
            if(nodeId == 1)
            {
                node.renderer.material.color = Color.black;
                nearby.Add(node);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach(GameObject node in _nodeList)
{
int nodeId = node.GetComponent<NodeScript>()._ID;
    foreach(int allergie in allergies)
    {
        if(nodeId != allergie && nodeId != identity)
        {
            Your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It only breaks the current loop

Comment: I posted more of the script above and I want it to skip the part after continue if that if statement is true